# Robolectric - BuildActivity(MyActivity.class).create() throw NullPointerException

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

I have project in Android Studio which was created in Eclipse. I migrated it to Gradle and added test. For test I use Robolectric. When I tested library modules in my project everything was ok, but when i start testing application module and call `BuilActivity(MyActivity.class).create().get()` console prints me that error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.res.builder.DefaultPackageManager.getActivityInfo(DefaultPackageManager.java:173)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.getActivityInfo(ActivityController.java:65)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.attach(ActivityController.java:51)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:121)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:304)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
    at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
    at test(test.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I don't know what cause this error. Anybody have something like that?

**EDIT**:
In project i use 7 modules. When i start test one module without activite everything works fine, but when i started test module with activity i've got above error stack trace.
**Activity**
In activity, fragment with viewpager is attached and activity starts data download using volley. This activity extends other class which extends another one, which blah blah blah...
**buil.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile project(':proj-core')
    compile project(':proj-gui-base')
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        test {
            resources.srcDirs = ['test']
            java.srcDirs = ['test', 'test/src/java']
        }

        robolectric.java.srcDir file('test/src/java')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

**Tests**
Problem starts in @Before method

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class Test {

    Context context;
    ShadowApplication shadowApplication;
    HomeActivity homeActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RuntimeEnvironment.application.onCreate();
        context = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext();
        shadowApplication = Shadows.shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
        homeActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(HomeActivity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_core_base_popup_popup() {

        Popup popup = new Popup(Popup.Type.GENERIC);
        PopupQueueManager.addPopup(homeActivity, popup);
        PopupQueueManager.displayAllPopups(homeActivity);
        assertEquals(popup.getContent(), "xyz");
    }
}
```

**Project Structure**
I describe only one of 7 modules. Every module have same structure.

```
proj-android  
|  
|-proj-core-base  
    |-assets  
    |-res
    |-src
       |- com.package
    |-test
       |-java
          |-Test.java
|-next-module  
|-next-next-module  
|-etc
```

Comment: Can you share build.gradle, test and activity onCreate code?

Comment: I've edited my post. @EugenMartynov

Comment: You don't need to call application oncreate, it will be done by Robolectric. Also remove context and shadowapplciation since you don't use it. And add `sdk = 21` into your config annotation for test

Comment: So, I remove what you recommend and add sdk to annotation, and ... .... doesn't work again. I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I’m using Android Studio 3.1.1 and also got a NullPointerException when calling Robolectric.buildActivity(…).create().get().  Then I found the following link:

http://robolectric.org/getting-started/

where it is recommended to add the following block to your app’s build.gradle file:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests { 
            includeAndroidResources = true 
        } 
    } 
}
```

With this addition the exception was avoided. I’m not sure if this solution works for your case. Just sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using an incompatible robolectric and android SDK versions:

With Robolectric 3, you should use :

```
MyActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't take any positive effect